# Laravel 5 Upgrade - Blade Form syntax

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I've recently upgraded my project from 4.2 to 5.1.

I've noticed that Forms in blades now have to use {!! ... !!} brackets around them.

My project has over 900 instances of Form calls.

From what I can see on the laravel site the only thing I can do is update every tag html line where I am using a Form.

Is this a sane decision? Bearing in mind I have to do this over 900 times.

Comment: Isn't it better to just stick with 4.2 then?

Comment: Hindsight is a wonderful thing, I've gone through the migration process for too long to turn back now unfortunately

Comment: Have you checked out the [Upgrade Guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade#upgrade-5.0) provided by the Laravel docs? Scroll down to the `Blade Tag Changes` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade#upgrade-5.0) state the following:

> For better security by default, Laravel 5.0 escapes all output from both the `{{ }}` and `{{{ }}}` Blade directives. A new `{!! !!}` directive has been introduced to display raw, unescaped output. The most secure option when upgrading your application is to only use the new `{!! !!}` directive when you are certain that it is safe to display raw output.
>
> However, if you must use the old Blade syntax, add the following lines at the bottom of `AppServiceProvider@register`:
>
> ```
> \Blade::setRawTags('{{', '}}');
> \Blade::setContentTags('{{{', '}}}');
> \Blade::setEscapedContentTags('{{{', '}}}');
> ```
>
> This should not be done lightly, and may make your application more vulnerable to XSS exploits. Also, comments with `{{--` will no longer work.

This is relative to the upgrade from 4.2 to 5.0, but since the upgrade from 5.0 to 5.1 is only minimal, this will still apply.